Restapi forbidden response in vb task
I have an API that I tested in Postman. I want to use this API in a task within my own software. I can call the Access Token, CSRF token, and cookies, but when it comes to sending the content I want with this information, I get a forbidden error and I haven't been able to find a solution.
My GetAccessToken function:
   Private Function GetAccessToken() As String
            Try
                Dim client As New HttpClient()
                Dim requestBody As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) From {
                    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_id", "myclientid"),
                    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_secret", "myclientsecret"),
                    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("scope", "*")
                }

                Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurl")
                request.Content = New StringContent(String.Join("&", requestBody.Select(Of String)(Function(a) a.Key & "=" & a.Value).ToArray()))
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result
                If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                    Dim result As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    Dim tokenResponse As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(result)
                    If tokenResponse.ContainsKey("access_token") Then
                        LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan GetAccessToken : {0}", tokenResponse.ToString()))
                        Return tokenResponse("access_token")
                    End If
                End If

                LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", "Token alma işlemi başarısız oldu.")
                Return Nothing
            Catch ex As Exception
                LoggerBase.LogUnidentifiedException(ex)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function

fetchcsrftokenandcookies function:
     Private Function fetchcsrftokenandcookies(token As String) As (String, String)
            Try
                Dim client As New HttpClient()
                Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "myurl")
                request.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", "fetch")
                request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " & token)
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result
                If Not response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "task", "csrf token alma işlemi başarısız oldu.")
                End If

                Dim cookies As String = String.Join("; ", response.Headers.GetValues("set-cookie").Reverse().Select(Function(c) c.Split(";"c)(0)))

                'Dim cookies As String = String.Join(";", response.Headers.GetValues("set-cookie").Select(Function(c) c.Split(";")(0)))

                Return (response.Headers.GetValues("x-csrf-token").FirstOrDefault(), cookies)
            Catch ex As Exception
                LoggerBase.LogUnidentifiedException(ex)
                Return (Nothing, Nothing)
            End Try
        End Function

This two function works (I think so) and I can see the results.
But
Post Function:
   Public Overrides Sub ExecuteExtender()
            Try

                Dim token As String = GetAccessToken()
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(token) Then
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", "Token alınamadı.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan Token : {0}", token.ToString()))

                ' CSRF Token Al
                Dim csrfTokenInfo As (String, String) = fetchcsrftokenandcookies(token)
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csrfTokenInfo.Item1) Then
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", "CSRF Token alınamadı.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan CSRF Token : {0}", csrfTokenInfo.Item1.ToString()))


                Dim client As New HttpClient()
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)

                Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurl")
                request.Headers.Add("x-csrf-token", csrfTokenInfo.Item1)
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", csrfTokenInfo.Item2)

                Dim json As String = "{" & vbCrLf &
                             "  ""date"": ""2024-03-10""" & vbCrLf &
                             "}"
                Dim content As New StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                request.Content = content

                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result
                Dim responseContent As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                    Me.ExecutionStatus = String.Format("Başarılı!")
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("ResponseContent : {0}", responseContent.ToString()))
                Else
                    Me.ExecutionStatus = String.Format("Başarısız!")
                    Dim errorContent As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("API çağrısı başarısız oldu. StatusCode: {0}, Hata Mesajı: {1}", response.StatusCode, errorContent))
                End If



            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub

and there is a second postdata function I tried before :
     Public Overrides Sub ExecuteExtender()
            Try
                Dim token As String = GetAccessToken()
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(token) Then
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", "Token alınamadı.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan Token : {0}", token.ToString()))

                Dim csrfTokenInfo As (String, String) = fetchcsrftokenandcookies(token)
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csrfTokenInfo.Item1) Then
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", "CSRF Token alınamadı.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan CSRF Token : {0} - Cokiee : {1}", csrfTokenInfo.Item1.ToString(), csrfTokenInfo.Item2.ToString()))

                Dim today As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                Dim requestBody As String = $"{{""date"": ""{today}""}}"
                Dim client As New HttpClient()
                Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "myurl")
                request.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrfTokenInfo.Item1)
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", csrfTokenInfo.Item2)
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
                request.Content = New StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result
                Dim responseBody As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

                If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                    Dim result As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.InfoMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("Alınan RESULT : {0}", result.ToString()))
                Else
                    Dim errorContent As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    LoggerBase.Log(LogMessage.Types.ErrorMessage, Now, 10, "TedasScheduledOutageTask", String.Format("API çağrısı başarısız oldu. StatusCode: {0}, Hata Mesajı: {1}", response.StatusCode, errorContent))
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                LoggerBase.LogUnidentifiedException(ex)
                Me.SetStatusText("Görev oluşan hata nedeniyle sona erdi: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub

I tried to copy my accesstoken to postman autharization so it's works. But I don't say my csrf token is valid.
